# Linux compare diff / meld

Tags: linux, file, comparison

I have this strange issue. I have created an algorithm that compresses Inverted Files. I have the original file (in my example it's 198.3Mb) and the decompressed file (which is 198.0 Mb). File sizes are viewed by Nautilus. I ran meld and it returns identical files. Format of both files is exactly the same. What is wrong ?!?!

Example (i ran sdiff (-s mode) and i got this, the exact same data):

```
170832              |               170832
170833              |               170833
170834              |               170834
170835              |               170835
170836              |               170836
```

How are these not identical by sdiff ?

Comment: Sounds like your algorithm just outputs the original file, possibly with some data that doesn't matter for the format.

Comment: Might be different line endings (Dos-style CRLF vs Unix-style NL)

Comment: I have created both files under linux, using the exact format layout (special chars '\t','\n') and with the same mode ('w')

Answer (score 1):

use e.g. `od -c` to analyze the lines that are reported different.
Each character is displayed, including \r \t and such, so you can see exactly where differences are.